# Show that the index of $r$ must be the sum of the indices of $p$ and $q$.

Tags: differential-topology

Could someone give me some help to get started with this question? Don't even have the slightest idea.. =(

> Suppose a vector field v on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has exactly two isolated zeros $p, q$, and $p, q$ are connected by a flow-line of the vector field. Furthermore, assume one can modify the
>   vector field in a compact neighborhood of the flow line and merge $p, q$ to give new vector
>   field $w$ with a single isolated zero $r$. Show that the index of $r$ must be the sum of the
>   indices of $p$ and $q$.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the definition of your "index"? Have you worked with the Hopf-Index theorem?

Comment: This requires a good deal of machinery. Your earlier questions about differential topology were at the beginning of the subject. How did you advance through three months of material to this?

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh I am just very unfortunate to encounter this question...

Comment: @ChrisGerig According to Guillemin & Pallock, the index of $\vec{v}$ at 0, to be the degree of this directional map $S_\epsilon \rightarrow S^{k-1}$.

Comment: You need a version of the Boundary Theorem, which will give you (generalizing the Argument Principle in complex analysis) such a conservation law, once you have all the definitions and tools.

Comment: Oh Thanks a lot @TedShifrin. That will take me sometime! =)

Comment: @TedShifrin what is the Boundary theorem you are referring to?

Comment: @LuigiM: The Boundary Theorem says that if $M$ is a compact orientable $(n+1)$-dimensional manifold with boundary and $N$ is a compact orientable $n$-dimensional manifold, then a map $f\colon\partial M\to N$ extends to $M$ if and only if $\deg(f)=0$.